# how components get updated when data store changes

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm new to React and still struggling in understanding in using redux with React.

For example, below is some code :

```
   const mapStateToProps = (storeData) => ({
      editing: storeData.isEditMode;
   })

   const mapDispatchToProps = {
      saveCallback: xxx
   }

   const connectFunction = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);

   export const ProductDisplay = connectFunction(
       class extends Component {
          render() {
             if (this.props.editing) {
                 ...
             } else {
                ...
             }
          }
      }
   )
```

and a component that uses `ProductDisplay`

```
export default class App extends Component {
   render() {
       return <ProductDisplay/>
   }
}
```

Let's say `storeData.isEditMode` is changed by other component, so the wrapped component's `props.editing` is changed. As we know that the only way to trigger update process is to use `setState()` but how does react know that `ProductDisplay` component needs to be updated since there is no `setState()` method involved?

Comment: It gets passed in as a prop, a component will rerender if props/state values change unless told otherwise.

Comment: @MattAft  isn't that a component will only rerender when `setState()` is called?

Comment: prop changes get checked as well. You can also manually trigger a re-render with `forceUpdate`. This article covers it pretty well: https://lucybain.com/blog/2017/react-js-when-to-rerender/

Comment: @MattAft  thanks for the link. But there is no relevant infomation on official docs says that prop changes get checked as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connect function generates a wrapper component that subscribes to the store. When an action is dispatched, the wrapper component's callback is notified. It then runs your mapState function, and shallow-compares the result object from this time vs the result object from last time (so if you were to rewrite a redux store field with its same value, it would not trigger a re-render). If the results are different, then it passes the results to your "real" component" as props.

Dan Abramov wrote a great simplified version of connect at (connect.js) that illustrates the basic idea, although it doesn't show any of the optimization work.

update

React-Redux v6.0.0 made some major internal changes to how connected components receive their data from the store.

For more details: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/04/02/redux-rerendering/

Comment: as you said, If the results are different, then it passes the results to your "real" component" as props. but how passing a different props to a component triggers the component to re render?

Comment: As props changed, then components re rendered. The components re render exists in reactjs on two conditions 1. State change and 2. Props change. It includes virtual dom of reactjs to perform rerender. For more details please visit https://lucybain.com/blog/2017/react-js-when-to-rerender/